# Удалите код JavaScript и CSS, блокирующий отображение верхней части страницы, но скрипты итак внизу

Tags: javascript, оптимизация-сайтов, pagespeed-insights

PageSpeed Insights Рекомендует исправить обязательно:

> Удалите код JavaScript и CSS, блокирующий отображение верхней части
>   страницы

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хотя все скрипты итак стоят внизу страницы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не понимаю что может быть причиной, как можно исправить?

Если дело в количестве подключаемых библиотек, то проверяла другую подобную страницу (с десятком подключаемых скриптов) и все в порядке. async не помогает, да и проблем с ним много.

**footer.tpl:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После скриптов контента нет.

Comment: так у тебя даже список дан что именно надо бы удалить. Далее смотри свою разметку: у тебя подключение стилей и скриптов идет **до** основной разметки страницы, вот на это и ругается. Перенеси их в конец body и предупреждение должно убраться

Comment: @Grundy, аж за тег `</body>` ?

Comment: Не, как раз перед этим закрывающим тегом, то есть: `...твои скрипты и стили...</body>`, либо еще вариант попробовать поставить скриптам и стилям атрибуты async и defer

Comment: @Grundy, как раз так и стоят. За скриптами именно контента больше нет. async не помогает

Comment: Да и очень проблематично использовать async

Comment: А ты уверена, что проверяется именно версия где они стоят? вверху страницы есть какие-нибудь скрипты?

Comment: @Elena "как раз так и стоят. За скриптами именно контента больше нет." - ну как же нет? У Вас на картинке есть html после скриптов.

Comment: @Grundy, Вы о том, что эти же скрипты могут быть вверху? Так нет, нет их там. В шапке остались скрипты метрики, аналитики и модернизр правда еще.

Comment: @Igor, call виджеты после идут, могу за ними переставить - не влияет

Comment: _В шапке остались скрипты метрики, аналитики и модернизр правда еще._ - модернизр, кстати, один из пунктов указанных. Перенеси _все_ скрипты из шапки в конец документа

Comment: Вон у тебя 4 дива и 2 инпута, перетащи их выше скриптов.

Comment: @vp_arth, "@Igor, call виджеты после идут, могу за ними переставить - не влияет!"

Comment: @Elena "могу за ними переставить" - переставьте, пожалуйста, и обновите картинки в вопросе, чтобы они отражали действительное положение вещей

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Как разобраться с блокирующим CSS я давал ответ [вот тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/364315/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-css-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B4/625536#625536). Дополнительно можете воспользоваться библиотекой [loadCSS](https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS) для загрузки неблокирующего CSS.

Куда вы разместите в странице ваши скрипты — в начало или конец документа — не имеет значения. В вашем случае совет следующий:

Во-первых, объединить все библиотеки-плагины и файл с их инициализацией в один файл, назовем его, к примеру, `main.js`.

Во-вторых, загружать jQuery по событию `load`:

```
function dlOnload() {
  var jq = document.createElement("script");
  jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js";
  document.body.appendChild(jq);
}

window.addEventListener("load", dlOnload, false);
```

В-третьих, запускать загрузку зависимых от jQuery файлов после его загрузки:

```
function dlOnload() {
  var jq = document.createElement("script"), mainScript;
  jq.src = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js";
  document.body.appendChild(jq);

  jq.onload = function() {
    mainScript = document.createElement("script");
    mainScript.src = "scripts/main.js";
    document.body.appendChild(mainScript);
  }
}

window.addEventListener("load", dlOnload, false);
```

И в-четвертых, всем скриптам, которым не важен порядок загрузки, добавить атрибут `async`.

---

UPD: для динамической загрузки скриптов с возможностью кэширования в *localStorage* рекомендую воспользоваться [basket.js](https://addyosmani.com/basket.js/). В вашем случае код будет выглядеть примерно таким образом:

```
basket
.require({ url: 'path-to/jquery.js' })
.then(function () {
    basket.require(
    { url: 'path-to/jquery-ui.js' },
    { url: 'path-to/jquery.fancybox.js' },
    { url: 'path-to/jquery.fancybox.pack.js' },
    { url: 'path-to/common.js' }
    );
}, function (error) {
    // Ошибка
    console.log(error);
});
```

Comment: Александр, а можете объяснить как вы решаете вопрос с погрузкой jQuery для тех проектов, в которых вы не можете проконтролировать когда он вам понадобиться?(допустим в середине php фаила идет AJAX запрос к серверу, и он идет с использованием jQuery, но ведь мы его согласно вашим описаниям загружаем первым, но только ПОСЛЕ всей загрузки DOM )

Comment: В 2022 еще действующий метод? А то с прошлого августа вообще проблемы(

Comment: @drtvader сейчас я бы так уже не делал, но наверное и в общем виде на вопрос теперь я бы отвечать не стал. работает ли метод до сих пор? скорее всего да, браузеры принципиально иначе работать не стали

Comment: А как делаете? Может пример где-то есть?

Comment: сейчас я бы упражнялся со вкладкой нетворк, профайлером, предварительно вооружившись статьями с CSS wizardry, по типу этой https://csswizardry.com/2018/11/css-and-network-performance/