# Оптимизация верстки(css файлы) под PageSpeed

Tags: javascript, css, оптимизация-сайтов

Добрый день уважаемые. Посоветуйте пожалуйста, как можно оптимизировать css-файлы для увеличения скорости загрузки страницы (кроме компрессии)? У меня в теге `head` *(index.html)* находятся стили для прелоадера, сжатый *normalize* (в теге `style`) и сжатая сетка *bootstrap3* (тоже в теге `style`). Ко всем остальным стилям (как видно из картинки), я ссылаюсь через `link`, но PageSpeed считает, что можно как то быстрее...

[image: скрин сайта]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Для скорости вы должны сформировать css обеспечивающий базовое отображение первой 1000 пикселей страницы, так называемый critical path css. Этот код нужно разместить на странице inline в теге head. В конце страницы можно разместить js загружающий полный css.

Comment: А можно как-то подробнее?(Особенно про js фаил который будет подгружать основные стили) На практике я пока только встречал, что основной фаил css разбивали на header.css и main.css и затем в тег head html-файла вставляли стили от header.css. Но всё равно PageSpeed говорит Оптимизируй!

Comment: `<!-- Load CSS --><script>var ms=document.createElement("link");ms.rel="stylesheet";ms.href="style.css";document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(ms);</script>` Этот код грузит css из файла style.css. Разместить нужно в конце страницы. Для того, чтобы создать critical path css можно воспользоваться сервисом https://jonassebastianohlsson.com/criticalpathcssgenerator/

Comment: Кстати то, что вы разбили css на разные файлы вредит скорости.

Comment: Так, что-то теперь вообще ничего не понятно. 1) В книгах пишут размещай файлы со стилями внутри <head>, вы же советуете в конце <body>, ещё и грузить через скрипт, с чем это связано?  2) Я конечно понимаю что в идеале (если не использовать async)  лучше что б количество css файлов было как можно меньше, но не могу ж я стилевые файлы со шрифтами мешать с стилями от слайдеров.

Comment: 1) Не файл со стилем нужно размещать в head, ведь именно на это ругается page speed. Там нужно разместить инлайн-css в тегах `<style>` но не весь, а в объеме выделеном сервисом critical path css. Важно, чтобы страница отобразилась, а потом можно загрузить полный css. Именно это мы делаем, когда размещаем в конце страницы приведенный js код, который по сути добавляет в секцию `head` мета-тег `link` со ссылкой на полный css файл.

Comment: 2) Пока все поголовно не перешли на http/2 на один домен выделяется 5 потоков, т.е. браузер клиента может качать с вашего сервера одновременно только 5 файлов, а они у вас все css. Конечно это ошибка. Поэтом наплевать на то, что шрифты и слайдеры - это разные части. Весь css в один файл.

Comment: 10 инструментов для оптимизации css https://postovoy.net/10-instrumentov-dlya-optimizacii-css.html

Comment: @kizoso для page speed эти сервисы не решат вопрос.

Comment: Спасибо за пояснения. Почему-то пока что ваш метод запустить не удалось. (Фото в первом сообщении) Я сделал как вы советовали, в <head> поместил только <style> с шапкой сайта, а основной фаил со стилями подгружаю через JS код в конце body. но он чего-то не загружается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Выделяем при помощи npm-модуля critical (или руками, или онлайн-сервисами) стили для above-the-fold (первого экрана), вставляем их в `<head>` в тег `<style>`.
2. Загружаем ваши основные стили при помощи `<link rel="preload" href="path/to/your/stye.css" onload="this.rel='stylesheet'" as="style" />` + используем *loadCSS + rel=preload polyfill*.
3. Если сайт адаптивный, то можно разбить ваш основной файл на несколько других по медиа-запросу и потом вставить их несколькими ссылками:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 320px)" href="mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 500px)" href="big-mobile.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="tablet.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="style.css" />
```

Таким образом, парсер при проходе будет игнорировать ненужные стили и браузер не будет их скачивать.

Другие мои подобные ответы по теме: [раз](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/639423/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-front/639835#639835), [два](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/636076/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-critical-rendering-path/636098#636098), [три](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/364315/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-css-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B4/625536#625536), [четыре](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/627279/%D0%A3%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4-javascript-%D0%B8-css-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%BE/627302#627302).