# Как определить ширину экрана средствами Django?

Tags: python, django, responsive

Хочу подключить файл стилей под определенную ширину экрана. Как получить ширину экрана от клиента?

Comment: Никак, только js и css media

Comment: @andreymal, получается надо через pageOnload отправлять ширину?

Comment: А чем css @media не подходит-то? Оно как раз предназначено для разных стилей под разную ширину

Comment: @andreymal, не хочу лишним кодом захламлять html файл. Под определенную ширину подключать определенный файл.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имел опыт с [вот этим](https://github.com/selwin/django-user_agents) пакетом.

После настройки - можно будет использовать такие теги шаблонов:

```
{% load user_agents %}

{% if request|is_mobile %}
    <link href="mobile.style.css">
{% endif %}

{% if request|is_tablet %}
    <link href="tablet.style.css">
{% endif %}

{% if request|is_pc %}
    <link href="pc.style.css">
{% endif %}
```

Т.е., технически - такая возможность есть. Но, как указал @andreymal, не надо так делать.

Comment: Мобильники нынче такие, что ширина некоторых шире экранов компов ;)

Comment: Там проверяется юзер-агент, а не ширина экранов.

Comment: Вот и я о том же, а вопрос-то именно про ширину

Comment: Слушать юзер-агент — порочная практика )

Comment: А ещё я бы рекомендовал использовать if/elif/else вместо if/if/if, а то, например, гугл вообще никаких стилей не получит и вдруг занизит сайт в результатах поиска)

Comment: ...хотя он и так занизит, потому что с таким решением не увидит поддержку мобильников на сайте

Answer (score 1):

Подключить файл стилей под определенную ширину экрана можно так:

```
<link href="style.css" media="(min-width: 50em)">
```

Правда с северным кодом это имеет мало общего :-)

Comment: это я знаю, спасибо :) просто не хочу html файл лишним кодом захламлять, а чисто под размер экрана подключать нужный файл стилей :)

Comment: @bytesmite размер окна браузера может в любой момент измениться уже после загрузки страницы, так что не надо так

Comment: @andreymal, то есть несколько link'ов прописывать под файл?

Comment: @andreymal, или в один файл все медиа-запросы запихать?

Comment: Ширина экрана может меняться уже после ответа сервера, потому загружать стили строго для одного экрана может оказаться не лучшей практикой. Но если все-таки очень хочется, то для этого можно использовать JS и загружать второстепенные стили асинхронного.

Comment: @bytesmite если вы хотите заняться оптимизацией загрузки CSS, посмотрите ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/641571/Оптимизация-версткиcss-файлы-под-pagespeed/642017#642017, может найдете что-нибудь новое для себя.